# How to read by streamreader and sort

Tags: c#, sorting, stream, leaderboard, reader

I'm making a passaparola game , at the end of the game i save nickname and score with stream writer as nickname;score

I'm trying to make a leaderboard but dont know how to sort them highest to lowest at or after saving.

Also to display them on labels i wrote this ;

```
        string[] scoreArray;
        string sc = sr.ReadLine();

        scoreArray = sc.Split(';');
        label2.Text = scoreArray[0];
        label3.Text = scoreArray[1];
```

which writes first line in text file.Anyway 
how can i sort and write them in labels ?

Answer (score 1):

Sort the array and then use a foreach loop to display the results:

```
string[] scoreArray;
string sc = sr.ReadLine();
scoreArray = sc.Split(';');
Array.Sort(scoreArray);
foreach (string s in scoreArray)
{
    //Your code here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension method of LINQ an option for you? For example like this:

```
        string line = "300;100;60;200;100;150";
        string[] scoreArray;
        int[] orderedScoreArray;

        scoreArray = line.Split(';');
        orderedScoreArray = (from score in scoreArray
            orderby Convert.ToInt32(score)
            select Convert.ToInt32(score)).ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < orderedScoreArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(orderedScoreArray[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort as you're reading from a Stream Reader.  You will have to either sort the values before saving them to the file, or read them all then sort them before displaying them.

Reading them all then sorting might look something like:

```
//define a class to store your scores
public class Score
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public decimal Score { get; set; }

    public Score()
    {

    }
}

//then reading the values
var scores = new List<Score>();
string line = "";
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    var lineArray = line.Split(';');
    scores.Add(new Score{ Username = line[0], Score = line[1] });
}

// then sort the list using linq
scores = scores.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).ToList();
```

Then you can go through the scores and display them however